# How to block vertical scroll while showing modal

Tags: css, bootstrap-modal, react-modal

In my React Project, I need to show a modal for mobile screen where it needs to cover all the screen and block scrolling for the content beneath. I tried to make `overflow-y: hidden` for body through useEffect when modal shows up, but I consider it not an ideal approach as I need a CSS only solution. Then I watched bootstrap modals already doing so only with CSS.
Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4"></div>
        <div class="col-4">
          <!-- Button trigger modal -->
          <button
            type="button"
            class="btn btn-primary"
            data-bs-toggle="modal"
            data-bs-target="#exampleModal"
          >
            Launch demo modal
          </button>
          <p>
            "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem
            accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa
            quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae
            dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit
            aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores
            eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est,
            qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit,
            sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore
            magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis
            nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut
            aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure
            reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae
            consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla
            pariatur?"
          </p>

          <!-- Modal -->
          <div
            class="modal fade"
            id="exampleModal"
            tabindex="-1"
            aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
            aria-hidden="true"
          >
            <div class="modal-dialog">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">
                    Modal title
                  </h5>
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    class="btn-close"
                    data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                    aria-label="Close"
                  ></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
                    Nullam lacinia elit tempor suscipit tincidunt. Mauris ac
                  </p>
                  <select
                    class="form-select"
                    aria-label="Default select example"
                  >
                    <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
                    <option value="1">One</option>
                    <option value="2">Two</option>
                    <option value="3">Three</option>
                  </select>

                  <div class="dropdown">
                    <button
                      class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle"
                      type="button"
                      id="dropdownMenuButton1"
                      data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                      aria-expanded="false"
                    >
                      Dropdown button
                    </button>
                    <ul
                      class="dropdown-menu"
                      aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1"
                    >
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                      <li>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"
                          >Something else here</a
                        >
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    class="btn btn-secondary"
                    data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                  >
                    Close
                  </button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                    Save changes
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone please tell from above code that which bootstrap class is preventing from scrolling the content?
Here is the codesandbox link for better demonstration: https://codesandbox.io/s/bootstrap-modal-locking-gryh94

Comment: Just because you are not directly invoking the Bootstrap JS doesn't mean the Bootstrap library is not using JS to achieve this behavior. Bootstrap is not a CSS-only library, and this behavior is not achieved with CSS only.

Comment: Can you please suggest a CSS solution?